# JQuery datepicker does not respond to click event of after clearing the textbox

Tags: jquery-ui-datepicker

I have tried rahul's code. It looks like this

```
$("input:text.inputTypeDate").datepicker({
        dateFormat: "dd/mm/yy",
        changeMonth: true,
        changeYear: true
    });
});
```

ASP

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtDt" runat="server" Width="120px" class="inputTypeDate">
</asp:TextBox>
```

It works fine on page load, but when I clear the textbox, it stops working.

Comment: What exactly happens when you clear the textbox?

Comment: are you using updatepanel?

Comment: tnx 4 qck reply. textbox got cleared. but wen i again click it the jqeury datepicker doesnt show.

Comment: no i m not using updatepanel.